# NullPointerException while reading a properties file in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, properties-file, fileinputstream

I have below code:

```
public class BasePage {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;
    FileInputStream objfile;

    @Test
    public void BasePages() throws IOException {
        try {
            prop = new Properties();

            objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("app.properties"));
            prop.load(objfile);
            System.out.println("file loaded");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("catch exception" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

The `FileInputStream` shows `NullPointerException`. I tried debugging the above code only after reading this line it moves to the catch block.

Can anyone explain why i'm getting Exception and how to solve this?

`app.properties` file contains below lines:

```
baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
browser="chrome";
```

Comment: ``` public void Initialization() {  
   
   String baseUrl = prop.getProperty("baseUrl");
   String browser = prop.getProperty("browser");
     System.out.println(baseUrl);
     System.out.println(browser);
     
    if(browser.contentEquals("chrome"))
    {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
     System.out.println("Chrome loaded");
    }
        
     System.out.println(baseUrl);
     System.out.println(browser);  
     driver.get(baseUrl);
    }}
```

Comment: why did u initialized "objfile' 2 time at class level and inside test function ??

Comment: It is a typing mistake i edited the code @Amit jain

Comment: objfile= new FileInputStream("give full properties file path")

Comment: @Madhu, If any answer is helpful for you then please do `accept` by click on tick mark below vote count. So it can be helpful for others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution:

```
   try {

    InputStream  objfile = new FileInputStream("path/to/app.properties")) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();

    // load a properties file
    prop.load(input);

    // get the property value and print it out
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("baseUrl"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("browser"));


} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objfile= new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("app.properties"));
```

The above line is causing the issue because `System.getProperty("app.properties")` returns null. Don't know why you are using this.

Just remove `System.getProperty()` as shown below. Make sure you are using right file path

```
objfile = new FileInputStream("app.properties");
```

If you intended to access current project directory then code should be

```
objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+"app.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. give full properties file path
   objfile= new FileInputStream("give full properties file path")
2. if 'objfile' which is an object is not created due to wrong path
3. and we are trying to dereference a null object, hence getting null pointer exception
   prop.load(objfile);

Note- i had given the answer fastest can be seen in comments section. please consider while accepting, thanks